# Is my ethernet port broken?

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, ethernet

Im on a macbook (black, model 4,1), and it seems my ethernet doesn't work. When I plug in the cable, System Preferences > Network says:

[image]

This suggest that the ethernet card is at least partially aware that there is a cable connected, and that's why I'm not 100% sure it is a hardware issue. The yellow light is consistent; it doesn't switch between green/yellow/red. Without a cable Network (obviously) says:

[image]

The network is configured with DHCP. Info:

- I've tryed plugging in other mac's and it configured automagically; worked straight away
- Internet works fine when the same cable is connected to my Airport
- Ethernet card is *Marvell Yukon Gigabit Adapter 88E8055 Singleport Copper SA*
- Ethernet doesn't work in Ubuntu either
- I can't ping anything.

So, bottom line: is the ethernet card broken, or could this be a software / configuration issue?

Comment: are any other computers on your network having problems getting an IP address?

Comment: Nope - when I connect on wireless instead, using the same cable and my wireless router, there are no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is try to set the IP manually - it could be some program is interfering and not allowing the interface to acquire a DHCP address (but unlikely as you have tried through Ubuntu).

If it still does not work, you have really tried everything that I would other than to use a separate router (just to rule out some freak compatibility problem between network card and router!) - so I would say that the socket is broken.

Comment: I'm going to try with another router.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to another router using the same cable, it's not your NIC. It's probably the first router. Did you reboot it?

Comment: I've tried multiple times with reeboots in between. Sounds right to try another router...